# NavigationController.view addSubView doesn't show the entire view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a popup view in a separate xib file. The view background has an 0.5 alpha and I only have a square in the center.

When I instantiate it and do an `addSubView` on it with the parent view, it works perfectly, but the child view doesn't show above the `navigationBar`. When I do the same, but with the parent navigationController's view, it only shows the 0.5 alpha background, and not the square.

In other terms :

```
// Works fine, but doesn't show itself above the NavigationBar
GDSubCategoryPopupViewController *subCategoryPopupView = [[GDSubCategoryPopupViewController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:subCategoryPopupView.view];

// Shows itself above the navigationBar, but only display the transparent background


GDSubCategoryPopupViewController *subCategoryPopupView = [[GDSubCategoryPopupViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:subCategoryPopupView.view];
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Say, have you implemented your `init` method of `GDSubCategoryPopupViewController` ?

Comment: `Cause if not - strange that it works

Comment: Yes i have it ! Can't figure out why the navigationController get rid of my square ... Tried the constraints and to put it at 0, 0 but it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiate your `GDSubCategoryPopupViewController` this way

```
GDSubCategoryPopupViewController *subCategoryPopupView = [[GDSubCategoryPopupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibname" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Well did some change, didn't even paste the good code... I actually did it, but my square doesn't show up

Comment: GDSubCategoryPopupViewController *subCategoryPopupView = [[GDSubCategoryPopupViewController alloc] init];
    
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:subCategoryPopupView.view];

This is what i actually did, gonna change it in my post. i did this mistake because i called the subview method, which has the parent view as a parameter to display it

Comment: I found the solution ... I actually had to add the child's viewController to the navigationController as well ... Weird that the navigationController asks for it, but not the parent's view ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Well, that is really weird. You're welcome! Good luck to you!